# Printing out elements in a list

Tags: c++, list, loops

```
Book Administrator::bookDetails()
{
    Book book;
    list<Book> books;

    string title;
    string author;
    int ISBN;

    string userInput;

    while (userInput != "q")
    {
        cout << "Would you like to enter a book?" << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput == "yes")
        {
            cout << "What is the title of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> title;

            cout << "What is the author of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> author;

            cout << "What is the ISBN of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
            cin >> ISBN;

            book.setTitle(title);
            book.setAuthor(author);
            book.setISBN(ISBN);

            books.push_back(book);

        }

        list<Book>::iterator pos;
        pos = books.begin();

        for (pos = books.begin(); pos != books.end(); pos++)
        {
                    //There error is produced here
            cout << *pos << "\n";
        }

    }
    return book;
}
```

This is the `bookDetails` function of my Administration class. It loops through and asks for a books title, author and ISBN number and when its finished it pushes the book onto a list.

This seems to work fine when i debug it but i get an error when i try to print out the details of each book using the iterator.

Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks

Comment: What did you type in the debugger, and what did the debugger say ?

Comment: _i get an error_ - what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `operator<<` for `Book`

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Book& book)
{
   os << book.title << " " << book.author; // print out other information
   return os;
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks a lot man. I'll choose your answer as soon as i can (8 more minutes)